# How to implement effect when SKSpriteNode is transparent but become visible with light?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklightnode

I would like to implement the effect when transparency of `SKSpriteNode` changes when it illuminated by light. By default `SKSpriteNode` is transparent but become visible with light.

Comment: So, what's your specific problem?

Comment: @Daniil You should update your question with a code that shows what you have tried so far. Also try to be more descriptive, or add a link to effect you are trying to achieve. Make it easier for people who answering :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague on context.

You can either use a sprite's alpha channel or use a SKLightNode.

If you decide on the alpha channel, a possible implementation would be to change the alpha settings depending on proximity to the player.

If you use a [SKLightNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLightNode_Ref/index.html), the node's light will illuminate the sprite dependent on a couple of settings. This implementation requires some trial and error.

Comment: I don't thing about first option, I will consider it.

I actually interested in second one. In general when object is not illuminated it is black I want it to be transparent. When illuminated, the illuminated part become opaque.

Comment: @Daniil - then you will have to manipulate the node's alpha setting.